# Proper Merging of 2 Camunda bpmn files into one at system run time

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I read Camunda BPMN Model API [here](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.5/user-guide/model-api/bpmn-model-api/), I am wondering if I can combine/merge two different predefined bpmn files into one bpmn file at runtime. I don't like parsing the bpmn files' xml content and combine it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with merging/combining? 
Two completely different BPMN Models? If yes: deploy them both and let them interact with messages.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I am thinking to create a single BPMN file with Call activities and link it to the names of predefined bpmn files. It can be done by runtime.

Answer (score 0):

So far I can merge the predefined BPMN models into one bpmn file by using activity call and linking the predefined BPMN models into it programatically.